# VBA input box not yielding to the user input

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA code to receive input from user and set the input a filter criteria, however, when the user input the value, and the function is executed, the filter criteria will be blank. I am having phone numbers which start with 0 as input.But when I manually set the filter criteria with the number the functions work. Could I get some help please.

Here is the code that works and the one that is giving me problem:

```
Sub sort()

A = InputBox("ENTER THE SUBJECT NUMBER")

    Range("A1:B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AD$6184").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "A"
    Range("A2").Select
    

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select

End Sub
```

After running this code the filtered columns is blank

```
Sub sort()

A = InputBox("ENTER THE SUBJECT NUMBER")

    Range("A1:B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AD$6184").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "08122816403"
    Range("A2").Select
    

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

While this one with direct input to the code works well

Comment: Welcome! What about `Criteria1:= A` instead `Criteria1:= "A"`?

Comment: Syntax has to be precice. `"A"` is filtering by the letter A, @JohnSUN mentioned using `A`, but that might be the object A. It may instead be `A.value`. Also you may need to wrap quotation marks, so it could even be """&A.value&""". Good luck.

Comment: Thanks all, I have tried the two syntax but non seems to have work it out, the targeted filter column has the filter applied but i see empty choice, meaning all the boxes unchecked thus empty cells appear all through

Comment: Thanks all, I have tried the two syntax but non seems to have work it out, the targeted filter column has the filter applied but i see empty choice, meaning all the boxes unchecked thus empty cells appear all through
A = InputBox("ENTER THE SUBJECT NUMBER")
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AD$854").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        """&A.value&"""
    Range("A2").Select
--
A = InputBox("ENTER THE SUBJECT NUMBER")
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AD$854").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "A.value&"
   Range("A2").Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the user input in variable A but filter by literal "A" as in the actual character. Just get rid of the quotes and it will work.
Correct code:

```
Sub sort()

    A = InputBox("ENTER THE SUBJECT NUMBER")

    Range("A1:B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AD$6184").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=A
    Range("A2").Select
    

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select

End Sub
```

Credits to [@JohnSUN's comment](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2730462).

Comment: This worked out the magic! Thanks a bunch!!